# pip command error during installation of requirements.txt

Tags: windows-10, python, cmd.exe, environment-variables

When I run the command `py -2.7 -m pip install requirements.txt`, I'm getting the error

[image: pip requirements error screenshot]

but I have already upgraded it

[image: pip upgrade screenshot]

but I'm still getting error in installing requirements.txt.

When I use the command `py -2.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip`. I am getting this exception

[image]

Comment: `py -2.7` may not be the same Python as `python`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

-r means to read from the file

but not able to understand why it was showing to upgrade.

Comment: It showing you might wish to upgrade because your version of pip is old. `pip` receives upgrades like any other package. If you use multiple installations of Python (e.g. Python 2.7 and Python 3.x), each Python version has its own version of `pip` that may need to be upgraded.

Comment: @Anaksunaman you can see screenshot that it is already upgraded.

Comment: In your screenshots, `py -2.7 -m pip` shows an outdated pip and `python -m pip` shows it's up to date, these are two different Pythons. What does `py -2.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip` return?

Comment: @hoefling I am getting some exception and this "You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command."

Comment: Copy the exception from the terminal and add it to the question.